# phpMyAdmin export database creation script without alter statements

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I can get query for creating a specific table via:

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE `table_name`
```

If I do this for all of the tables, I can recreate the whole database by running the gathered sql queries. Is there an easier way to get the table creation script, i.e. sql export file, which created the database just by using `CREATE` statements?

Comment: Unexpected start of statement:. (near "mysqldump" at position 0)

Comment: `mysqldump` is a program you run, not a SQL statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would solve this with mysqldump. It's a command-line tool that comes with MySQL. Here's the documentation: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqldump.html

You run it at a command prompt, not in phpMyAdmin. You must have access to a shell environment that is either the same host where you run MySQL Server, or at least can reach that host via the network.

For example:

```
mysqldump --no-data mydatabase mytable
```

Output is produced:

```
--
-- Table structure for table `mytable`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `mytable`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `mytable` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `c1` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `c2` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `c3` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

(There's more output that I'm omitting.)

You can dump the structure of many tables at once this way, and also views, triggers, procedures, and so on.

If you don't use `--no-data`, it also includes the data in each table you dump. This makes it an effective tool for data backups. By default, it dumps data in the form of a lot of `INSERT` statements. So just like the CREATE TABLE statements can recreate the structure of your database if you run them against another MySQL instance, the INSERT statements can recreate your data.